# Do I need to install Datatools to use TFS build on a Solution that has a Database Project

Tags: c#, build, database-project

We are working on configuring TFS for all our Build/Deploy options and I have been testing this by creating a Build Controller to our TEST system. However when I run the build task, I get this

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets
>   (395): Incompatible versions of SQL Server Data Tools and database
>   runtime components are installed on this computer. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225934 for more details

The solution has a DB Project in it, but all I care about is the application from a Build Standpoint (I Excluded the project in VS 2012)

I know to fix this for development, I needed to install the new Data Tools at the link provided. Do I need to do this on the Build Server as well?

Let me know if any questions need answering.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'd be better off making sure that the latest SSDT components are also installed on the build server. MS made some changes in the Dec 2012 release of SSDT that improve several things, but also made some changes to the underlying projects. In general, it's probably just a good idea to keep the version on your build server in sync with the one you're using for projects.